# Drawing a rectangle in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xna

This is a very simple question but I couldn't find anything on the internet that was helpful. Basically, I am trying to draw a rectangle but when I launch my code nothing is happening (I don't have any errors either). Here is the code:

```
class Buildings
{

    public void test(Game1 mainGame, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        var buildingrect = new Rectangle(mainGame.bufferHeight - 30, 50, 200, 50);
        // (Note: mainGame.alien2 is a texture I have - this isn't the problem) 
        spriteBatch.Draw(mainGame.alien2, buildingrect, Color.White);
    }
}

public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        buildings.test(this, spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help and I apologize again for this being such a simple question - I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Have you checked if the `Rectangle` has values that are visible when rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not draw rectangles simple like that. You can solve it like this:

Create a texture that holds the pixelcolor for the rectangle

```
private Texture2D pixel;
private Rectangle rect; //your rectangle`
```

Initialize it with your preferred color:

```
pixel = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
pixel.SetData(new[] { Color.White });`
```

In your `draw` method you now draw each side of your rectangle:

```
int bw = 2; // Border width
//Left
spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, bw, rect.Height), Color.Black);
//Right
spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(rect.Right, rect.Top, bw, rect.Height), Color.Black);
//Top
spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, rect.Width, bw), Color.Black);
//Bottom
spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Bottom, rect.Width, bw), Color.Black);
```